# How do I use my laptop as a screen for PS3?

Tags: ati, laptop, hdmi, ps3

I have a ASUS M51Tr laptop with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series graphic card. I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 and privative controllers. I want to use the HDMI port to play PS3 as if the laptop was a screen.
Note: I don't want any kind of PS3 emulator or that sort of things.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would love to be proven wrong, because it would be frickin sweet to use your laptop to display game console output. But. The HDMI port is an output. All it does is send stuff from the graphics card to whatever is plugged into it. Same thing goes for the PS3. If you plug your PS3 into it, they're just gonna sit there sending output signals at each other.

[Check out the specs for your card.](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-3000/hd-3400/pages/hd-3400-specs.aspx) I don't see anything about it having an input port.

What MAY be possible, and lofi, is installing a TV tuner card to your computer and using the antenna input on the TV tuner card to take the coax output from your PS3.

Comment: Thanks. But if I had an input port, would it be simply connect and play?

Comment: More or less. There might be something in the ATI control panel that would let you choose between inputs, or do picture in picture.  You wouldn't want the PS3 to take over your screen, you'd want to choose between Ubuntu and the PS3.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible. The HMDI port on your laptop is most likely an output only port and so as such you can't pipe your PS3 output through it and onto your laptop screen. You can only use it to attach a HDMI enabled display to your laptop as an extra screen. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, since the HDMI ports of laptops are for OUTPUT only, and you want to use it as INPUT.

That would only be achieavable using an add-on video input card, impossible to install in a laptop.

Comment: Impossible to install? I would've agreed had I not seen some of the crazy eeepc hacks. Difficult, but not impossible. Consider the possibility of a USB video input (USB vid-out already exists).